# How to save only recently generated plots?

Tags: r

I have used this code to save the plots that I have generated:

```
plots.dir.path <- list.files(tempdir(), pattern="rs-graphics", full.names = TRUE); 
plots.png.paths <- list.files(plots.dir.path, pattern=".png", full.names = TRUE)
file.copy(from=plots.png.paths, to="C:/Users/c/Downloads/Compressed/Amde's/Bahir Dar")
```

but it worked correctly once. And when I generated a second bach of different plots, the number of plots are more than the once I generated the second time.

Is there any way I could save the plots that I have generated recently?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have two copies of your plots. One which is present in `from` (`plots.png.paths`) and another in `to` (`"C:/Users/c/Downloads/Compressed/Amde's/Bahir Dar"`). You can keep the plots only in `to` folder so that you'll have the latest plots available always in your `from` directory. This can be done by using `file.rename` instead of `file.copy`.

```
plots.dir.path <- list.files(tempdir(), pattern="rs-graphics", full.names = TRUE); 
plots.png.paths <- list.files(plots.dir.path, pattern=".png", full.names = TRUE)
file.rename(from=plots.png.paths, to="C:/Users/c/Downloads/Compressed/Amde's/Bahir Dar")
```

Comment: I don't have two copies of my plots. I wanted to copy the recently generated plots from R temporary directory to my directory ( which is supposed to be chanaged everytime a new batch of plots are generated).

Comment: In addition when i tried it brought this error: Error in file.rename(from = plots.png.paths, to = "C:/Users/c/Downloads/Compressed/Amde's/Debere Tabor") : 
  'from' and 'to' are of different lengths

Comment: You can try with `file.rename(from=plots.png.paths, to=paste0("C:/Users/c/Downloads/Compressed/Amde's/Bahir Dar/", basename(plots.png.paths)))`

Comment: No error but it just simply brings out one empty image. But the images that my code generates are 45.